# PayPal , return page post values, how to access and use

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am wrestling with the PayPal service .   I almost have it done .  Last step,  when the customer payed and has the last page, which stays open for 10 seconds and then redirects them to the page of your choosing.

What parameters, posts, etc are sent with that page opening? And how do I get access to them, so I can link the returning user with their created account (from ipn and my personalized database entry on the initial buyitnow)

I tried echo($_post). But it just shows ....  Array()   But no key value pairs.

I'd think there would be a lot more

I have rm=2. Set already.

Plus,  I see some Get() cars in the URL but,  nothing I can use .

Also, I am passing a custom variable ,  which is going through, and being used by the IPN to update the user account just fine.  I just don't see how to connect the return page and the customer, preferably with the $custom var

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `var_dump($_POST);` instead of `echo($_post);`

Comment: This is what I get for var_dump..  for that...                        array(0) { }           I would think that Paypal sends something.... no?

Comment: var_dump($_POST);     ONLY does the above....                                                              But.. This works:    $tx_token = $_GET['tx'];
      echo($tx_token); I can get a number from this...  unfortunately, I need my $custom var

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there are no POST variables coming from PayPal, they're all GET variables. A `VAR_DUMP(GET)` will show like 6 things, including your CUSTOM variable (id `cm`). I thought there would be more and it would be in POST format.

I also thought there would be a way to show everything, POST, GET, SESSION, etc. I even tried using Firefox NETWORK setting, but there were like 50 separate items. None of which seemed to contain my data. I'm sure it was there, but, hidden.